# 'charset=UTF-16' is missing in the transformation result with MSXML4.0

Tags: xslt, character-encoding

I have some problems about "charset" in the transformation result with different versions of MSXML.

The code below will transform XML to HTML with MSXML3.0

```
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.async = False
    Dim strXML As String
    strXML = "<Results><ElapsedTime>3000</ElapsedTime></Results>"
    xmlDoc.loadXML(strXML)

    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument
    xslDoc.async = False
    Dim strXSL As String
    strXSL = "C:\Test.xsl"
    xslDoc.load(strXSL)

    Dim xslt As New MSXML2.XSLTemplate
    xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc

    Dim xslProc As MSXML2.IXSLProcessor
    xslProc = xslt.createProcessor
    xslProc.input = xmlDoc
    xslProc.transform()

    Debug.Print(xslProc.output)
```

================================

The content of "Test.xsl" is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Results">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Report</title>
      </head>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

===============================

The output is,

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
<title>Report</title>
</head>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why the charset is always set as "UTF-16" with MSXML3.0

=========================

Then I change code to use MSXML4, like this,

```
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument40
...
Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument40
...
Dim xslt As New MSXML2.XSLTemplate40
...
```

=====================

This time, the output is,

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Report</title>
</head>
</html>
```

No charset is output in MSXML4.0.

=====================

Can you please tell me which one is right?
Why the differences happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general MSXML sucks at getting the right character encoding.  For some frekking reason they've chosen UTF-16 as default charset.

But you could try to add this line right after the xsl:stylesheet line:

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
```